# Google Maps InfoWindow placed in center of the map?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I wanna place the InfoWindow in my google Maps center of the map-Window. Is this possible?

Unfortunatly there is no option in the InfoWindow options like this

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    positionMiddleOfWindow: true    });
```

Someone knows how to place the InfoWindow in the middle of the map window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the coordinates of the center of your map, then create the infowindow with that location

```
var lat = map.getCenter().lat(); 
var lng = map.getCenter().lng();
```

or get the latLng in one piece:
`var latlng = map.getCenter();`

Comment: Mhm... I tried this and add to my infowindow the following var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: contentString, position: LatLng(lat,lng) }); But now there is an Error

Comment: I've pointed to an Lat Lng with an adress and this marker has an infobox, and I want that the infobox is in the middle of the map not the position of the marker.

Comment: how about this: `position: map.getCenter()`?

Answer (score 5):

First, set the map to center on the marker. You can check the domready event of the InfoWindow and scroll the map a little left and bottom so that the InfoWindow is centered.

**jQuery**

```
pin=new google.maps.LatLng(50.00, 50.00);

marker=new google.maps.Marker({
    position:pin,
});

marker.setMap(map);
map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());

// The InfoWindow
myWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content:'<p id="myId">My InfoWindow</p>',
});

myWindow.open(map, marker);

google.maps.event.addListener(myWindow, 'domready', function() {
    // Get the actual height of the InfoWindow
    e = $('#myId').parent().parent().parent();
    h = parseFloat(e.height());
    w = parseFloat(e.width());

    // Move the map a little to the left and down
    map.panBy(-w/2, h/2)
});
```

Comment: How will we do when we have more than 1 marker and all info windows are opened then want to center the google map? Please share your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of moving the map or calculating the height or width just use the following function. The trick here is to delay sometime before we open the infoWindow. We should setZoom and setCenter and delay 300 milliseconds before we open the infoWindow and the google maps api will open the infoWindow right in the center how it should be:

```
function OpenInfoWindowCentralized(map, infowindow, marker) {
    map.setZoom(16);
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());

    setTimeout(function() {
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }, 300);
}
```

I hope it helps in some way...

Cheers